# Java Error On Midterm Exam

Tags: java, recursion

I had this piece of code on one of my exams

```
public static int mystery(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 1;
    if (b > 1) return result *= ( a * a, b / 2);
    if (b % 2 == 1) return result *= a; 
    return result;
}
```

and what I was trying to find was what the value at the end would be if we used `mystery(2, 5)`. I think the answer is 32, but that is not the problem. The problem is when I tried to implement that code snippet on Eclipse to see if I got the answer right I got an error message that read

```
The primitive type int of a does not have a field b
Syntax error on token ",", . expected
```

because of the line of code that reads `if (b > 1) return result *= ( a * a, b / 2);`. If anyone can tell me why that error message is showing up and how to fix it, I would appreciate it. Also do you guys think I should tell my professor that his code doesn't even compile without errors?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `if (b > 1) return result *= mystery( a * a, b / 2);`?

Comment: Be happy, when he did this mistake this question will not be counted. The right result is 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have

```
if (b > 1) return result *= ( a * a, b / 2);
```

when it should probably be

```
if (b > 1) return result *= mystery( a * a, b / 2);
```

Comment: You're right, but in the question it doesn't use recursion, so I think maybe the professor forgot to include it.